# Is simulating the interaction of multiple particles possible in $0$ spacelike and $3$ timelike dimensions?

Tags: spacetime, computational-physics, simulations, spacetime-dimensions, causality

In multiple time like dimensions it is possible for particles to effect it's own past, and two particles can both be effected by each others future.  I tried to simulate the interaction of multiple electric charges in $0$ spacelike and $3$ timelike dimensions, in MS Excel, using iterative calculations, and proper time step increments, and got an error message in all the cells involved in the iterative calculations.

Is the issue simply to do with the type of program I was using, or due the violations in causality in multiple timelike dimensions actually make it impossible to simulate the interactions of multiple particles in multiple timelike dimensions?

Comment: How did you do the simulation? What mechanics and which equations did you use? In special relativity, having 0 spacelike and 3 timelike dimensions would be equivalent to 3 spacelike and 0 timelike dimensions. It is not clear to me how anything would propagate at all in such a space.

Comment: @StijnB. I used the rows for the characteristics of the particles, and the columns for the proper time step increments.  I found the unadjusted acceleration vector of each particle event from each other particle event by dividing the distance vector by the distance, multiplying the product of the charges, multiplied by the cosine of the angle between the velocities, divided by the square of the distance, divided by the mass of the event, and added all the acceleration vectors of that particle event up.

Comment: @StijnB. For the adjusted acceleration vectors I put the unadjusted acceleration through a formula that would shrink it until it was perpendicular to the velocity.  Next I would use the general parametric equation of a circle to get the new time position vectors, and the derivative of that with respect to the proper time step increments to get the new time velocity vectors.  Note also that when I say acceleration, position, and velocity that I am referring to the equivalent of the four position, four velocity, and four acceleration, with the total velocity always being 1.

Comment: It is still not at all clear to me what you actually simulated, and where the dimensions of space-time come in. A step-by-step walkthrough of your work, including mathematical equations, would maybe be helpful. Funnily enough, a free particle in 3-dimensional Euclidean space could be at one single point (minimizing its "proper time"), but I do not understand how you would define anything like a force (which relates timelike directions to spacelike directions) in such a setting.

Comment: @StijnB.  In special relativity the spacetime we live in could be thought of as four dimensional euclidean space if you think of there being three real spatial dimensions and one imaginary spatial dimensions, however free particles are not at one point in spacetime, but have infinitely many points, as they are one dimensional world lines in four dimensional spacetime.  So in my simulation I presumed that particles would be one dimensional world lines in three dimensional euclidean time as well.

Comment: @StijnB. A point on the world line of an electrically particle will "experience" a force from every other point that is on the world line of an electrically charged particle, rather or not it is in the present of that point.  In order to calculate the total force acting on the point, you have to add up the sum of the force from every other point.  Because there are three dimensions, in this simulation, the force between any two points that are both on the world lines of charged particles depends on the inverse of the square of the distance between these two points.

Comment: @StijnB.  Let me know when you have seen my last two replies, and if you have any more questions, and I will try to answer them, or go into more detail on the equations I used in my simulation, and how I derived those equations.